# Superclass using subclass version of method?

Tags: java, class, subclass, superclass

I can see how a subclass gets to inherit a superclass method, but what if the superclass wants to use the subclass version of the method?

Comment: It can't, shouldn't, and doesn't. Unless you mean through polymorphism, which is automatic. I don't know what you're asking anymore.

Comment: Define an abstract method in the super class, then use it inside another method of the super class. The behavior will belong to the specific subclass that overrides it, e.g.: defining an `public abstract void init()` method to load configurations.

Comment: So want I wanted to understand is that there is no sort of reverse or backwards inheritance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general answer to your question is to have your superclass call an overridable method on itself. Here's an example:

**Superclass**

```
public class MyClass {

    // This method calls other (overridable) methods on itself
    public void run() {
            doSetup();
            doAction();
            doCleanup();
    }

    /** 
     * These three methods could be abstract if there's no default behavior
     * for the superclass to implement. In this example, these are concrete 
     * (not abstract) methods because there is a default behavior.
     */

    protected void doSetup() {
            System.out.println( "Superclass doSetup()" );
    }

    protected void doAction() {
            System.out.println( "Superclass doAction()" );
    }

    protected void doCleanup() {
            System.out.println( "Superclass doCleanup()" );
    }
}
```

**Child class**

```
public class MySubclass extends MyClass {

    /**
     * Override a couple of the superclass methods to provide a different 
     * implementation.
     */

    @Override
    protected void doSetup() {
            System.out.println( "MySubclass doSetup()" );
    }

    @Override
    protected void doCleanup() {
            System.out.println( "MySubclass doCleanup()" );
    }
}
```

**Test Runner**

```
public class Runner {

    public static void main( String... args ) {

            MyClass mySuperclass  = new MyClass();
            mySuperclass.run();  // calls the superclass method, gets the superclass
                                 // implementation because mySuperclass is an instance 
                                 // of MyClass

            MyClass child = new MySubclass();
            child.run();  // calls the superclass method, gets the child class 
                          // implementation of overridden methods because child is 
                          // an instance of MySubclass
    }
}
```

For an example of a design pattern where this approach is used, see the [Template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Comment: You may want to add the explicit `@Override` annotation in the subclass.

Answer (score 6):

In the superclass you then will need to define the method abstractly.

Example:

```
abstract protected void doSomething();
```

And then `@Override` this method in the subclass.

Now your superclass knows about this, and can call it.

**Edit**, this also requires the superclass to be abstract, as else you cannot have `abstract` methods on a class.

Comment: Doing this requires that both classes be compiled together, at the same time, forever more. Unless you really know what you're doing, this kind of circular dependency is not recommended. When *anything* needs to be fixed, *everything* in the dependency-chain must be fixed before *any* of it will work.

Comment: @aliteralmind I can imagine that in almost all situations those classes should be in the same package, or at least the same project, whenever you are using such design.

Comment: Agreed. In limited situations, this is useful.

Answer (score -1):

This is a typical use case for the [Template Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern#Structure)

Comment: I mean, if your superclass needs to call a specific subclass implementation means that it is providing a sort of skeleton for further steps whose implementation can be known only at runtime. 

If this is not the case and you are trying to invoke a subclass method from its superclass, it is a bad OOP.